# Carriage return in text area

Tags: .net, jquery, textarea

I have to allow the user to enter carriage returns in text areas; something like:

> Sentence 1
>  Sentence 2
>  ...

I have to persist those carriage returns when loading and saving data.
I use jQuery on the client side, and .NET on the server. Any suggestions on how to approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "persist" the line breaks (`CRLF`) you mean that you want to display it properly, as SO does, you need to remeber to replace the `CRLF` pair with `<br/>CRLF`.

Otherwise, all your text will appear sequentially.

Comment: that is what I want, but found that just replacing .replace(/\r/g, '\r<br>'); is not working consistently

Comment: If you're using RegEx I'd go with .replace(/\r\n/g, "\r").replace(/\r/g, "\n<br>")

Comment: If youre using php, you can take the contents of the textarea and use nl2br() to convert new lines ("\n") to <br />

Comment: Even simpler: .replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br>\n")

Comment: Thanks, I forgot completely... it's the hour I think... and I guess decaf.. :-\

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special. That's what `<textarea>`s do, and unless you make a specific effort to strip out the newlines on the server side you'll load the save them with a standard `string` no problem.

Comment: ...except in our old friend IE.  I've got a similar issue where I'm returning a preformatted ASCII text file (with CRLFs) via a jquery AJAX call to populate a <textarea>.  Works great in FF, Safari, Opera, Chrome, even Dolphin on my phone.  But IE 7,8,9 ignore the CRLFs and I can one long illegible line.

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery .val() hook](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$.valHooks.textarea = {
    get: function( elem ) {
        return elem.value.replace( /\r?\n/g, "\r\n" );
    }
};
```