# div contenteditable="true"

Tags: jquery, html

Okay!... I'm facing this for hours now...

**html**

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="width: 509px; "></div>

<textarea cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
​
```

**jQuery**

```
$('div').keyup(function(){
    $('textarea').val($(this).text());
});
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
    $('div').html($(this).val());
})​;​
```

I want it that whatever I type in the <div>, would look **as is** in the <textarea> and vice versa... but I'm stuck... [please see my Fiddle for what I mean...](http://jsfiddle.net/JVnNv/)

for the reason is that, I'm using <div> as a replacement for <textarea>... because <div>'s scrollbar is easy to customize than of the <textarea>... but if you can see, contenteditable div would include another div when you press enter...

**edit**
what's happening is,

in the div,

> I
> am
> crazy.
> but
> your
> way
> of
> coding
> is
> worst.

but in textarea, using `.html()` in div

```
I<div>am</div><div>crazy.</div><div>but</div><div>your</div><div>way</div><div>of</div><div>coding</div><div>is</div><div>worst.</div>
```

.text() is like this

> I am crazy. but your way of coding is worst.

and really, I don't want that...

Comment: Looks like it's working in jsfiddle. You're typing in one area and not seeing the other change?

Comment: what I mean, is I need the carriage return `enter`.. line break or something....

Comment: you can't transfer a carriage return without some special logic that detects if the key pressed is the enter key and then inserts a carriage return programmatically :\

Comment: @Jason - yes.. and I have tried `.replace()`... but my logic is not good.. cause I can't seem to figure it out... I'm still on it..

Comment: Reigel -- my answer does exactly that.

Comment: nope... Sorry Kerry, it was not the answer....

Comment: to be sure i understand, the goal is to type into a contenteditable div, and transfer the text into a textarea.  the appearance doesn't matter so much as the underlying content that makes it appear that way.  does that sound right?

Comment: @ Reigel - does now :) and the other one did what I thought you wanted.

Comment: @nathan - if you mean by the css look, that really don't matter... but if you press enter on div, textarea should also... and vice versa...

Comment: Note: there is no such attribute as "contenteditable" in standard HTML.

Comment: @Rob - Yes... I know that,,.. but it's supported by most major browser, so I'm alright with that....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'd be easiest to use phpjs.org's nl2br function:
http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br:480

---

EDIT (fully working -- tested)

I tested this on your fiddle and it worked:

```
$('div').keyup(function(){
    $('textarea').val( $(this).html().replace( /<br>/g, '\n' ) );
   //$('textarea').val($(this).html()) // also not working as expected
});
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
    $('div').html( nl2br( $(this).val(), 0 ) )
});

function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
    // Converts newlines to HTML line breaks  
    //
    // version: 1004.2314
    // discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br    // +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   improved by: Philip Peterson
    // +   improved by: Onno Marsman
    // +   improved by: Atli Þór
    // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman    // +      input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // +   improved by: Maximusya
    // *     example 1: nl2br('Kevin\nvan\nZonneveld');    // *     returns 1: 'Kevin\nvan\nZonneveld'
    // *     example 2: nl2br("\nOne\nTwo\n\nThree\n", false);
    // *     returns 2: '<br>\nOne<br>\nTwo<br>\n<br>\nThree<br>\n'
    // *     example 3: nl2br("\nOne\nTwo\n\nThree\n", true);
    // *     returns 3: '\nOne\nTwo\n\nThree\n'    
    var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '' : '<br>';

    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1'+ breakTag +'$2');
}
```

Comment: i believe he means that new line characters are not being transferred, not that he wants the text transferred on enter.

Comment: I did not try it cause I know it won't work... contenteditable div makes another div inside it if you press enter... please see my edit above for the example scenario... thanks though... almost there.. ;)

Comment: It actually did not make another div when you pressed enter, if you noticed I had tested. I did, however, find another bug, and that is now fixed. Copy and paste the code in your fiddle and try it.

Comment: yes it did... have you tried firebug?.. or chrome dev tool?... you can see that the markup has change... when pressing enter, you will get <div><br></div>... and by pressing any key again, you'll get <div>some text here</div>... inside contenteditable divs... well, for .html() on div

Comment: I think you can do it, but I will if you want me to, simple regex will remove all divs. `.replace(/<\/?div>/, '')` for instance

Answer (score 1):

This code works in Firefox:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('div').keydown(function(){
    $('textarea').val($(this).html().replace(/<br>/g,"\n"));
  });

  $('textarea').keydown(function(){
    $('div').html($(this).val().replace(/\n/g,"<br>"));
  })
});
```

Then, if you're using Opera, the browser makes line breaks as `<p>....</p>`. IE, which Reigel probably use, probably adds those `<div>...</div>` tags. Seems there's no real standard way on how to handle line breaks when the DIV tag is contenteditable.

Comment: are you with me?... you're just posting my codes... what's the diff?

Comment: You don't notice the "html()" instead of "text()"?

Comment: oh??? and you did not notice my `please see my Fiddle for what I mean...` link?... it got that **(all of that)** code you posted.. XD

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things:
You can use the nobr tag
You can also add the style attribute:

```
<div style="display:inline;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036185/carriage-return-in-text-area) perhaps?  slightly different situation as he's trying to communicate to the server, but i think the answer should be similar.

this code was previously posted by Gert G, but it seems to have disappeared.  the code below seems to work flawlessly, so rep to Gert G on this one.

```
  $('div').keydown(function(){
    $('textarea').val($(this).html());
  });

  $('textarea').keydown(function(){
    $('div').html($(this).val().replace(/\n/g,"<br />"));
  })
```

Comment: doesn't work flawlessly... transfers carriage returns from txtarea to div, but not the other way around

Comment: Thanks for testing it nathan. It did work (well, with the exception that I hadn't done the div portion of the code when you grabbed the code. :) ). You seem to be using Firefox.

Comment: @Gert G, not a problem.  i wanted to make sure the code was seen mainly.  good job.

Comment: No problem nathan. I deleted the post (which wasn't done by the system, so I fixed up the code and updated the post) because I got ticked off at Reigel's response.

Answer (score 0):

I think must be like this:

```
$('div').keyup(function(e){ 
   $('textarea').val($(this).text().replace('<br>',/\r\n/ig)); 
}); 
$('textarea').keyup(function(e){ 
        $('div').html($(this).val().replace(/\r\n/ig, '<br>')); 
});
```