# div is crashing my Internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

My application is having 4 tab, in the middle tab I have used the content editable DIV. As soon as I (within a fraction of seconds) move to the tab and click on editable div and press space or any character it crashes my IE8. If I wait till the cursor (2 to 3 second) to blink once then it works fine with no issues.

This issue noted only in IE not in Firefox. it works smooth in Firefox.

Here is the code

```
 <div id = "myDiv" contenteditable = "true" class = "size"></div>
.size{
    float: left;
    width: 390px; 
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;

    background-color: #FFFFFF;

    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;

    overflow-x:Auto;    
    overflow-y:Auto;    

    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    white-space : normal;
}
```

Crash details

```
AppName: iexplore.exe    AppVer: 8.0.6001.18702  ModName: mshtml.dll
ModVer: 8.0.6001.23543   Offset: 00085e7c
```

Comment: How do you feel about providing a link to the page?

Comment: Provide us some Fiddle or link to work with?

Comment: Did you check the application in another machine? giving the same output?

Comment: it crashes in all machines. The error signature in error report shows ModName as "mshtml.dll"

Comment: well, I don't have IE8 anymore. And its hard to tell what could the root cause for this issue. I guess some code is responsible for this. Are you using any framework to build the application?

Comment: No, its asp.net MVC application running on .net 3.5

Comment: possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978909/div-contenteditable-true